# If cart item count is three – hide add to cart | shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We are looking for a solution, where the customer is not able to put more than three products in the cart. The whole thing should be done with a alert message and a hidden add to cart button if you have three items in your cart.

The problem is, that we use a ajaxify cart. The basic tutorials that are provided by shopify do not work.  Same with apps.

Here is a Link to our shop:
[printnil.com](http://printnil.com/products/urkundenmappe?variant=1010445695)

How to hide the add to cart button if you have three items in your cart?

```js
if ((typeof Shopify) === 'undefined') {
  Shopify = {};
}

Shopify.money_format = '${{amount}}';

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// API Helper Functions
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function floatToString(numeric, decimals) {
  var amount = numeric.toFixed(decimals).toString();
  if(amount.match(/^\.\d+/)) {return "0"+amount; }
  else { return amount; }
};
function attributeToString(attribute) {
  if ((typeof attribute) !== 'string') {
    attribute += '';
    if (attribute === 'undefined') {
      attribute = '';
    }
  }
  return jQuery.trim(attribute);
}
function getCookie(c_name) {
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
  }
  else {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
      c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
  return c_value;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// API Functions
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.formatMoney = function(cents, format) {
  if (typeof cents == 'string') cents = cents.replace('.','');
  var value = '';
  var patt = /\{\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}\}/;
  var formatString = (format || this.money_format);

  function addCommas(moneyString) {
    return moneyString.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3}[\.,]?)/,'$1,$2');
  }

  switch(formatString.match(patt)[1]) {
    case 'amount':
      value = addCommas(floatToString(cents/100.0, 2));
      break;
    case 'amount_no_decimals':
      value = addCommas(floatToString(cents/100.0, 0));
      break;
    case 'amount_with_comma_separator':
      value = floatToString(cents/100.0, 2).replace(/\./, ',');
      break;
    case 'amount_no_decimals_with_comma_separator':
      value = addCommas(floatToString(cents/100.0, 0)).replace(/\./, ',');
      break;
  }
  return formatString.replace(patt, value);
};

Shopify.onProduct = function(product) {
  alert('Received everything we ever wanted to know about ' + product.title);
};

Shopify.onCartUpdate = function(cart) {
  alert('There are now ' + cart.item_count + ' items in the cart.');
};

Shopify.updateCartNote = function(note, callback) {
  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/update.js',
    data: 'note=' + attributeToString(note),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(cart) {
      if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(cart);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onCartUpdate(cart);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);
};

Shopify.onError = function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
  var data = eval('(' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ')');
  if (!!data.message) {
    alert(data.message + '(' + data.status  + '): ' + data.description);
  } else {
    alert('Error : ' + Shopify.fullMessagesFromErrors(data).join('; ') + '.');
  }
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// POST to cart/add.js returns the JSON of the line item associated with the added item.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.addItem = function(variant_id, quantity, callback) {
  var quantity = quantity || 1;
  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: 'quantity=' + quantity + '&id=' + variant_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(line_item) {
      if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(line_item);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onItemAdded(line_item);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// POST to cart/add.js returns the JSON of the line item.
//   - Allow use of form element instead of id
//   - Allow custom error callback
// ---------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.addItemFromForm = function(form, callback, errorCallback) {
    var params = {
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/add.js',
      data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(line_item) {
        if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
          callback(line_item, form);
        }
        else {
          Shopify.onItemAdded(line_item, form);
        }
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        if ((typeof errorCallback) === 'function') {
          errorCallback(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
        }
        else {
          Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
        }
      }
    };
    jQuery.ajax(params);
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// GET cart.js returns the cart in JSON.
// ---------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.getCart = function(callback) {
  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function (cart, textStatus) {
    if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
      callback(cart);
    }
    else {
      Shopify.onCartUpdate(cart);
    }
  });
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// GET products/<product-handle>.js returns the product in JSON.
// ---------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.getProduct = function(handle, callback) {
  jQuery.getJSON('/products/' + handle + '.js', function (product, textStatus) {
    if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
      callback(product);
    }
    else {
      Shopify.onProduct(product);
    }
  });
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// POST to cart/change.js returns the cart in JSON.
// ---------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.changeItem = function(variant_id, quantity, callback) {
  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/change.js',
    data:  'quantity='+quantity+'&id='+variant_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(cart) {
      if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(cart);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onCartUpdate(cart);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);
};


/* Modernizr 2.7.0 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
 * Build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-touch-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes
 */
;window.Modernizr=function(a,b,c){function y(a){i.cssText=a}function z(a,b){return y(l.join(a+";")+(b||""))}function A(a,b){return typeof a===b}function B(a,b){return!!~(""+a).indexOf(b)}function C(a,b){for(var d in a){var e=a[d];if(!B(e,"-")&&i[e]!==c)return b=="pfx"?e:!0}return!1}function D(a,b,d){for(var e in a){var f=b[a[e]];if(f!==c)return d===!1?a[e]:A(f,"function")?f.bind(d||b):f}return!1}function E(a,b,c){var d=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.slice(1),e=(a+" "+n.join(d+" ")+d).split(" ");return A(b,"string")||A(b,"undefined")?C(e,b):(e=(a+" "+o.join(d+" ")+d).split(" "),D(e,b,c))}var d="2.7.0",e={},f=b.documentElement,g="modernizr",h=b.createElement(g),i=h.style,j,k={}.toString,l=" -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- ".split(" "),m="Webkit Moz O ms",n=m.split(" "),o=m.toLowerCase().split(" "),p={},q={},r={},s=[],t=s.slice,u,v=function(a,c,d,e){var h,i,j,k,l=b.createElement("div"),m=b.body,n=m||b.createElement("body");if(parseInt(d,10))while(d--)j=b.createElement("div"),j.id=e?e[d]:g+(d+1),l.appendChild(j);return h=["&#173;",'<style id="s',g,'">',a,"</style>"].join(""),l.id=g,(m?l:n).innerHTML+=h,n.appendChild(l),m||(n.style.background="",n.style.overflow="hidden",k=f.style.overflow,f.style.overflow="hidden",f.appendChild(n)),i=c(l,a),m?l.parentNode.removeChild(l):(n.parentNode.removeChild(n),f.style.overflow=k),!!i},w={}.hasOwnProperty,x;!A(w,"undefined")&&!A(w.call,"undefined")?x=function(a,b){return w.call(a,b)}:x=function(a,b){return b in a&&A(a.constructor.prototype[b],"undefined")},Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(b){var c=this;if(typeof c!="function")throw new TypeError;var d=t.call(arguments,1),e=function(){if(this instanceof e){var a=function(){};a.prototype=c.prototype;var f=new a,g=c.apply(f,d.concat(t.call(arguments)));return Object(g)===g?g:f}return c.apply(b,d.concat(t.call(arguments)))};return e}),p.touch=function(){var c;return"ontouchstart"in a||a.DocumentTouch&&b instanceof DocumentTouch?c=!0:v(["@media (",l.join("touch-enabled),("),g,")","{#modernizr{top:9px;position:absolute}}"].join(""),function(a){c=a.offsetTop===9}),c},p.csstransforms=function(){return!!E("transform")},p.csstransforms3d=function(){var a=!!E("perspective");return a&&"webkitPerspective"in f.style&&v("@media (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){#modernizr{left:9px;position:absolute;height:3px;}}",function(b,c){a=b.offsetLeft===9&&b.offsetHeight===3}),a};for(var F in p)x(p,F)&&(u=F.toLowerCase(),e[u]=p[F](),s.push((e[u]?"":"no-")+u));return e.addTest=function(a,b){if(typeof a=="object")for(var d in a)x(a,d)&&e.addTest(d,a[d]);else{a=a.toLowerCase();if(e[a]!==c)return e;b=typeof b=="function"?b():b,typeof enableClasses!="undefined"&&enableClasses&&(f.className+=" "+(b?"":"no-")+a),e[a]=b}return e},y(""),h=j=null,e._version=d,e._prefixes=l,e._domPrefixes=o,e._cssomPrefixes=n,e.testProp=function(a){return C([a])},e.testAllProps=E,e.testStyles=v,e}(this,this.document);


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ajaxify Shopify Add To Cart
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var ajaxifyShopify = (function(module, $) {

  'use strict';

  // Public functions
  var init;

  // Private general variables
  var settings, cartInit, $drawerHeight, $cssTransforms, $cssTransforms3d, $isTouch;

  // Private plugin variables
  var $formContainer, $btnClass, $wrapperClass, $addToCart, $cartCountSelector, $cartCostSelector, $toggleCartButton, $cartContainer, $closeCart, $drawerContainer, $refreshCartCallback;

  // Private functions
  var updateCountPrice, drawerSetup, showDrawer, hideDrawer, setToggleButtons, formOverride, itemAddedCallback, itemErrorCallback, cartUpdateCallback, refreshCart, adjustCart, adjustCartCallback, scrollTop, isEmpty, log;

  /**
   * Initialise the plugin and define global options
   */
  init = function (options) {

    // Default settings
    settings = {
      debug: true,
      method: 'drawer',
      formSelector: 'form[action="/cart/add"]',
      addToCartSelector: 'input[type="submit"]',
      cartCountSelector: null,
      cartCostSelector: null,
      toggleCartButton: null,
      btnClass: null,
      wrapperClass: null
    };

    // Override defaults with arguments
    $.extend(settings, options);

    // Select DOM elements
    $formContainer     = $(settings.formSelector);
    $btnClass          = settings.btnClass;
    $wrapperClass      = settings.wrapperClass;
    $addToCart         = $formContainer.find(settings.addToCartSelector);
    $cartCountSelector = $(settings.cartCountSelector);
    $cartCostSelector  = $(settings.cartCostSelector);
    $toggleCartButton  = $(settings.toggleCartButton);
    $refreshCartCallback = settings.refreshCartCallback;

    // CSS Checks
    $cssTransforms   = Modernizr.csstransforms;
    $cssTransforms3d = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
    $isTouch         = Modernizr.touch;

    // Touch check
    if ($isTouch) {
      $('body').addClass('ajaxify-touch is-touch');
    }

    drawerSetup();

    if ( $addToCart.length ) {
      // Take over the add to cart form submit
      formOverride();
    }

    // Run this function in case we're using the quantity selector outside of the cart
    adjustCart();
  };

  updateCountPrice = function (cart) {
    if ($cartCountSelector) {
      $cartCountSelector.html(cart.item_count);
    }
    if ($cartCostSelector) {
      var price = Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price);

      $cartCostSelector.html(price);
    }
  };

  setToggleButtons = function () {

    // Reselect the element in case it just loaded
    $toggleCartButton  = $(settings.toggleCartButton);

    if ($toggleCartButton) {

      // Turn it off by default, in case it's initialized twice
      $toggleCartButton.off('hover');

      $toggleCartButton.on('hover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( $drawerContainer.hasClass('shoppingbagshow') ) {
          hideDrawer();
        } else {
          showDrawer(true);
        }

      });

    }
  };
  


  drawerSetup = function () {
    /* This function is completely changed from the original.
     * Vivetta has its own drawer structure, so we don't need to create one.
     */

    // Drawer selectors
    $drawerContainer = $('#shoppingBag');
    $cartContainer   = $('.shoppingbag__listcontain');

    setToggleButtons();
  };

  showDrawer = function (toggle) {

    // opening the drawer for the first time
    if ( !cartInit && toggle) {
      Shopify.getCart(cartUpdateCallback);
    }


  };


  
            

  formOverride = function () {
    $formContainer.submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Remove any previous quantity errors
      $('.qty-error').remove();
      Shopify.addItemFromForm(e.target, itemAddedCallback, itemErrorCallback);
    });

  };

  itemAddedCallback = function (product) {
    Shopify.getCart(cartUpdateCallback);
  };

  itemErrorCallback = function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    var data = eval('(' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ')');
    if (!!data.message) {
      if (data.status == 422) {
        $formContainer.append('<p class="qty-error">'+ data.description +'</p>')
      }
    }
  };

  cartUpdateCallback = function (cart) {
    // Update quantity and price
    updateCountPrice(cart);

    refreshCart(cart);
    showDrawer();
  };

  refreshCart = function (cart) {
    $drawerContainer.load('/cart #shoppingBagInner', function() {
      log('cart loaded from /cart');

       
     // This line triggers the callback, which will 
      // run JS manipulating the cart.
     $refreshCartCallback(cart);
     
      
      // Tell our plugin that the cart has loaded
      cartInit = true;

      // With new elements we need to relink the adjust cart functions
      adjustCart();
    });
  };

  adjustCart = function () {
    // This function only runs if the entire cart is reprinted.
    // To be safe, turn off the previous clicks that were assigned.
    var qtyAdjust = $('.qty__sub, .qty__add'),
        qtyNew = 0;

    // Add or remove from the quantity
    qtyAdjust.off('click');
    qtyAdjust.on('click', function() {
      var el = $(this),
          id = el.data('id'),
          qtySelector = el.siblings('.qty__num'),
          qtyCurrent = parseInt( qtySelector.val() );

      // Add or subtract from the current quantity
      if (el.hasClass('qty__add')) {
        qtyNew = qtyCurrent + 1;
      } else {
        qtyNew = qtyCurrent - 7;
        if (qtyNew < 0) qtyNew = 0;
      }

      // If it has a data-id, update the cart.
      // Otherwise, just update the input's number
      if (id) {
        updateQuantity(id, qtyNew);
      } else {
        qtySelector.val(qtyNew);
      }
    });

    // Update quantity based on input on change
    var qtyInput = $('.qty__num');
    qtyInput.off('change');
    qtyInput.on('change', function() {
      var el = $(this),
          id = el.data('id'),
          qty = el.val();

      if (id) {
        updateQuantity(id, qty);
      }
    });
    

    // Highlight the text when focused
    qtyInput.off('focus');
    qtyInput.on('focus', function() {
      var el = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.select();
      }, 50);
    });

    function updateQuantity(id, qty) {
      var row = $('.shoppinglist__product[data-id="' + id + '"]').addClass('is-loading');

      if ( qty == 0 ) {
        row.addClass('is-removed').slideUp();
      }

      // Slight delay to make sure removed animation is done
      setTimeout(function() {
        Shopify.changeItem(id, qty, adjustCartCallback);
      }, 250);
    }

    // Save note anytime it's changed
    var noteArea = $('textarea[name="note"]');
    noteArea.off('change');
    noteArea.on('change', function() {
      var newNote = $(this).val();

      // Simply updating the cart note in case they don't click update/checkout
      Shopify.updateCartNote(newNote, function(cart) {});
    });

    // Reset toggle buttons
    setToggleButtons();
  };

  adjustCartCallback = function (cart) {
    // Update quantity and price
    updateCountPrice(cart);


    // Reprint cart
    Shopify.getCart(refreshCart);
  };


  isEmpty = function(el) {
    return !$.trim(el.html());
  };

  log = function (arg) {
    if (settings && settings.debug && window.console) {
      try {
        console.log(arg);
      }
      catch (e) {}
    }
  };

  module = {
    init: init
  };

  return module;

}(ajaxifyShopify || {}, jQuery));
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to hide the cart after 3 items are in it? Don't you want people to buy more, rather than less?

Comment: We use the cart for product samples.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://your-store.myshopify.com/cart.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { 
        var item_count = data['item_count'];

        //If there are items in cart
        if(item_count > 3) {
            $('#add-to-cart').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Also

if you see this (http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api) Ajax API you can make a call to GET /cart.js and you will get `item_count` in response then you can put a `if` block to check if it's greater than 3 and then hide the button.

Comment: Great. The add-to-cart button disappear after page refresh. A just in time response would be great. I am trying...

Comment: You can use a spinner and show the page only after finishing querying the cart items.

Comment: This only seems to work with 'GET'. When I try 'POST' is doesn't allow it due to CORS